# Find partial matches in email addresses from @ symbol onwards in two unequal excel columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been carrying out some email marketing and have so far been comparing any new email addresses due to go out against a master list in excel of all previous emails sent, and then just removing any duplicates in the new list due to be sent using conditional formatting to highlight duplicates.

I thought this was a good way to do it, but have encountered a bit of an issue. People have multiple email addresses so john@ john.smith@ etc, and of course different people in the same company crop up.

I need a way to compare all the emails I have ever sent in column A, to a smaller list of emails in Column B, but ideally I want a way that will show up duplicates from the @ symbol onwards so I can then remove them

I have tried a few formulas but I haven't got the brain power to work out how to search just for domain matches, any ideas?

Comment: show some example data of what you have now, and what you want to achieve

Comment: So if i had john@theinternet.com somewhere in column A, I would like a way of highlighting if any other email address ending @theinternet.com was in column B somewhere. I would run the conditional formatting first to highlight any actual duplicates, but then ideally need a formula to highlight just matching domains only

Comment: Add the example data and desired results as a text table (preferable) or a screenshot by **editing** your question.  It'll be much easier to interpret than your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the domain from a list of email addresses with this function:

```
=MID(A1:A3,FIND("@",A1:A3,1)+1,LEN(A1:A3))
```

Adjust ranges appropriately.

[image]

Do the same thing for your shorter list, so that you now have a domain column for each list.

You can use this conditional formatting rule to highlight items in the short-list domain with items in the long-list domain:

[image]

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND($D1,$B:$B,1)))
```

Comment: Given that the domain is always the rightmost piece of text, using `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1))` is probably a slightly simpler formula.

Comment: Thank you all, had a play around and that is really helpful.